# Laravel Eloquent Relationship "one to many", got an error "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, migration, eloquent

according to the following code 
i try to create a relationship between "section" and "tours"
but i got error 
`Table 'yourproject.sections' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from 'sections' where 'sections'.'id' = 1 limit 1)` 

 and i use migrate to create a table "section" not "sections"

note : if i add a table name to a model i get a new error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tours.section_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tours` where `tours`.`section_id` = 1)
```

and i use migrate to create a column "sectionid" not "section_id"

Model
Section.php

```
<?php
class Section extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'section';
    protected $fullable = array('tit');
    public function tours(){
        return $this -> hasMany('Tours');
    }
}
```

Tours.php

```
<?php
class tours extends Eloquent{
    protected $fullable = array('tit','sectionid');
    public function section(){
        return $this -> belongsTo('Section');
    }
}
```

Migrations
Section

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSectionTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('section',function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('tit');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('section');
    }

}
```

Tours

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateToursTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tours',function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('tit');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('sectionid')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('sectionid')->references('id')->on('section');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tours');
    }

}
```

Route

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
$hotes = Section::find(1)->tours()->get();
return $hotes->tit;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your foreign key column name doesn't follow the naming convention of Laravel you have to specify it:

```
public function tours(){
    return $this->hasMany('Tours', 'sectionid');
}
```

And

```
public function section(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Section', 'sectionid');
}
```

Comment: I add a foreign key in migration file `$table->integer('sectionid')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('sectionid')->references('id')->on('section');`
and also add 'sectionid' in relation method as you say and still have the error

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'yourproject.sections' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sections` where `sections`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

Comment: Thought you had fixed that with `protected $table = 'section';` (which is the right thing to do by the way)

Comment: I do it and got this error
<br /><br />
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tours.section_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'tours' where 'tours'.'section_id' = 1)`

i dont know why laravel use names for tables that i didn't use??!!

Comment: And that second error should be gone by adding `sectionid` to the relation... Again, Laravel has certain naming conventions. So it will assume names if you don't specify them. For example the default table name is the plural of the model name.

Comment: Now i have this error  `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$tit`

Comment: Well `tours()->()` returns multiple models in a collection. You can't use it like a single model.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link all you need to know about naming conventions is here and relationships in laravel

http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships